# Pointing the root path to a html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

cant figure this out at all although it seems like it should be so simple.

I have 2 controllers, application and pages; within application I have the method index defined but without any actions.

In routes.rb I say: `root 'application#index'` my understanding is that this tells the route GET that if the root path is called then pass to the controller 'application' and carry out the 'index' action. How do I then tell the Index to open the file index.html.erb

Any help would be much appreciated. Thx

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'pages/home'
 get 'pages/about'
 get 'pages/app'
 root 'application#index'

end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def index

  end
end
```

Comment: `ApplicationController` is the base controller of all other controllers, it never contains any `index` action. Instead create something `WelcomeController` or `HomeController` for your main route.

Comment: You know just as you were typing that I figured it out thanks for responding . I added the index.htm.erb to the pages controller and everything is hunky dory...I'm a doofus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I should answer this myself in case anyone stumbles upon it. As pointed out by Iceman the action can't go in the application controller. My worry was that by putting it into the pages controller it would be subject to the pages path. Not so. Correct (or at least a working version) layout below:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'pages/home'
 get 'pages/about'
 get 'pages/app'
 root 'pages#index'
end
```

there is no need to amend the 'pages_controller' only to add the index.html.erb file to the pages 'View' folder.

Hope that helps someone.